# Binding of Procs

Tags: ruby, binding

Is it possible to execute a proc within the context of another object?

I know that normally you'd do proc.call(foo), and then the block should define a parameter. I was wondering though whether I could get "self" to bind to foo so that it's not necessary to have a block parameter.

```
proc = Proc.new { self.hello }

class Foo
  def hello
    puts "Hello!"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

# How can proc be executed within the context of foo
# such that it outputs the string "Hello"?

proc.call
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
foo.instance_eval &proc
```

`instance_eval` can take a block instead of a string, and the `&` operator turns the proc into a block for use with the method call.

Comment: Can anyone give me a documentation link for this? It certainly works (and is **really** awesome), but I'd like to read the docs. :)

Comment: If you run ```foo.instance_exec(params, &proc)``` you can also pass parameters to the function in the context.

Comment: Just used the @Sideshowcoder solution on Capybara to reuse some block of code and I had a nerd/devgarsm. Made my code so much beautiful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is for ruby 1.9:

```
class MyCat
  def initialize(start, &block)
    @elsewhere = start
    define_singleton_method(:run_elsewhere, block) if block_given?
  end
end
MyCat.new('Hello'){ @elsewehere << ' world' }.run_elsewhere
```